# read, replace placeholders and write a word file with docx4j

Tags: java, docx4j

I have a Word File look like this:
[image]

You don't need to understand the content, just take a look to my placeholders `<env>` and `<applikationsabkürzung>`. There are 10 pages with these placeholders and now I should replace them with other content. The black and yellow box are company pictures which I won't share.

Now I started to read the whole [docx4j doc](http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/docs/Docx4j_GettingStarted.html) and generate after some time the following code:

```
public void manipulateWord(String path, String env, String appl) {
    try {
        WordprocessingMLPackage wpml = WordprocessingMLPackage.load(new File(path));

        MainDocumentPart mdp = wpml.getMainDocumentPart();

        List<Object> content = mdp.getContent();

        // Include all Strings to replace
        HashMap<String, String> mappings = new HashMap<String, String>();
        mappings.put("<env>", env);
        mappings.put("<applikationsabkürzung>", appl);

        for (Object object : content) {
            Text textElement = (Text) object;
            String textToReplace = textElement.getValue();
            if (mappings.keySet().contains(textToReplace)) {
                textElement.setValue(mappings.get(textToReplace));
            }
        }

        wpml.save(new File("C:\\Users\\kristina\\Desktop\\outputfile.docx"));

    } catch (Docx4JException e) {
        LOG.error(e);
    }
```

Some explanaition:

- `String path` is the path of the file in the picture above
- `String env` is the value which should replace `<env>`
- `String appl` is the value which should replace `<applikationsabkürzung>`

But when I run the method, nothing happen, my console just print just some infos. If they're important, i'll edit the post, but i don't think so.

So where is my fault? Would it work like that? I'm shortly before to despair...

Comment: Are you sure `textElement.getValue()` is returning *<env>* and not *was<env>85...*? In that case `contains()` doesn't work

Answer (score 3):

`MainDocumentPart.getContent()` will return all OpenXml components within the main document flow (things like headers and footers have their own elements). Your code is assuming that the result of `List<Object> content` will be a collection of `Text` elements, which is not necessarily the case. For example, a typical (simple) document structure would be like this:

```
P  // Paragraph element
    -> R  // Run element
        -> Text  // Text element
```

… so `getContent()` is, in all likelihood, going to spit out a load of `P` objects for a start.

There are a few ways to traverse docx4 files -- see the main docx4j site for more -- but one approach is shown in the method below. You can pass in `MaindocumentPart` as the first Object, and `Text.class` as the object type to search for. This should then assist in identifying all `Text` elements which contain one of your mapping values:

```
public List<Object> getAllElementFromObject(Object obj, Class<?> toSearch) {
    List<Object> result = new ArrayList<Object>();
    if (obj instanceof JAXBElement)
        obj = ((JAXBElement<?>) obj).getValue();

    if (obj.getClass().equals(toSearch))
        result.add(obj);
    else if (obj instanceof ContentAccessor) {
        List<?> children = ((ContentAccessor) obj).getContent();
        for (Object child : children) {
            result.addAll(getAllElementFromObject(child, toSearch));
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```